# SQL Select average from results of DISTINCT rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

I'm trying to calculate a set of averages associated with each DISTINCT row in a SQL Server DB and I'm having trouble figuring out how to stitch it all together.  I'll illustrate with a simple example.  Here is the table that describes the time it took to get between 3 points A,B, and C.  I am trying to figure out the average time it took to get between each DISTINCT trip.

```
|Start|End|Time|
|  A  | B | 5  |
|  A  | B | 10 |
|  A  | B | 3  |
|  A  | C | 20 |
|  A  | C | 22 |
|  B  | C | 10 |
|  B  | C | 8  |
```

I would like the results of the query to produce

```
|Start|End|Avg|
|  A  | B | 6 |
|  A  | C | 21|
|  B  | C | 9 |
```

I've tried some thing with joins and nested selects with `SELECT DISTINCT Start,End` but I'm having some serious syntax problems figuring this one out.  Not too much experience with SQL.

Matt

Comment: Simply `GROUP BY`, combined with `AVG()` set function. (No select distinct...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `AVG` aggregate function with `group by`

```
SELECT Start,End,AVG(Time) Avg
FROM T 
GROUP BY Start,End
```